# Analytical function of this landscape

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, continuity

Hey I'm looking for an analytical (or at least with an analytical inverse) continuous function that has this "landscape" please, and I welcome even differential equations that this function would respect :
[image]

Meaning : $$\lim_{r\rightarrow \pm\infty} f(r)=0$$, $$\lim_{r\rightarrow \pm\infty} f'(r)=0$$ and $f(0)=0$ and $f(\pm a)=b$ with $a>0$ and $b>0$, if we make it simple : $$f(\pm 1)=\pm 1$$.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you mean $f(1)=\color{red}-1?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like
$$
f(x)=-\frac{x}{1+x^2}
$$
Or
$$
f(x)=-x\exp(-\lambda x^2),\quad\lambda>0.
$$